# Using Java to parse record with new lines

Tags: java, json, parsing

I would like to write a method to parse the following records from a file. It is possible for me read each line, start the record at "{" and end it at "}" and process each line in between. However, I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of processing records.

{\n
    "name": "Jeff Hamilton",\n
    "address": "101 Main St.",\n
    "id":"701"\n
},\n
{\n
    "name": "Peet Rizzo",\n
    "address": "109 Main St.",\n
    "id": "1003"\n
}\n

Comment: the more elegant way would be checking what this format represents and using a proper formater in order to retrieve the data..

Comment: what have you tried so far, or do you want us to solve this issue?

Comment: I assume it's json and can be parsed as such...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split this string into an array.

```
String newArray[]= str.split("\n },\n {\n");
```

You can also use a regex here.

Alternatively, a better approach would be to use JSON parsers.
I usually use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) for serialization/deserialization but you can use any.